# Batch Count .txt Files and echoing filenames after function based on count

Tags: variables, batch-file, count

I have a working batch script that counts .txt files in a directory tree (including subdirectories) then IF the count GTR than 2 basically notifies the user that they must do something before running this script again.

What I would like is for the script when notifying the user to also tell them the filenames of the txt file.

This is what I have.

The following checks the root folder and all sub directories for .txt files.
This counts the number of .txt files and sets it.

```
@echo off & Setlocal
:: Search for files in the Tree
Set "sFolder=C:\folder\folder\root"
Set "sFileType=txt"
set "i=0"

PushD "%sFolder%" &&(
  FOR /R "." %%i IN (*) DO ( If /i "%%~xi"==".%sFileType%" ( set /a i+=1 ) ) )
```

If the count is above 3 goto notify user (which is simple echo commands)

```
If %i% GTR 2 goto NotifyUser
```

What I do not get is how I could echo the 3 or more found .txt filenames to the user.  I understand it would be a variable but I can't seem to figure it out and how to put it in the above commands.

Also.. on the echoing there are times the filenames may have a " . " in the name more than the extension

IE:  filename.txt.gpg

The count command above does NOT count the example filename as a .txt file...
but the echoing of the name depending on the command could think this is a txt file ..I do not want the above filename example to echo to the user as one of the counted txt files (since it is NOT counted).  (hope that makes sense).

Comment: Instead of enumerating _all_ files (`*`), you could let the `for /R` loop already do the filtering of `*.txt` files; so there is no need for the `if /I` statement. And instead of `pushd [...] && (for /R [...])` I would use `pushd [...] && ((for /R [...]) & popd)`...

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to scan for .txt files more than once, so the simplest solution is to store the list of files in a temporary file, and type out the result if and only if the number of lines is greater than 2. You can use FIND to count the lines, and FOR /F to capture the count result.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "root=C:\folder\folder\root"
set "out=%temp%\myTextFileList.txt"
dir /b /s /a-d "%root%\*.txt" >"%out%"
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" <"%out%"') do if %%N gtr 2 (
  echo You cannot proceed because you have more than 2 .TXT files:
  type "%out%"
  del "%out%"
  pause
  exit /b
)
del "%out%"
REM Rest of script goes here
```

Comment: For some reason using this just makes the batch open and close very quickly even with a pause at the end.  Not sure what it is at the moment but typically its because of some typo somewhere.

Comment: @user2150312 - Look at the logic - the pause needs to be within the IF block. Edit made.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want to do is echo the names that gave you the total you echoed, you can use this:

```
@echo off & Setlocal
:: Search for files in the Tree
Set "sFolder=C:\temp"
Set "sFileType=txt"
set "i=0"

PushD "%sFolder%" &&(
      FOR /R "." %%i IN (*) DO ( If /i "%%~xi"==".%sFileType%" ( set /a i+=1 &echo %%~ni) ) )
```

Comment: That seems easy enough but is there a way to echo the files AFTER the GOTO notifyuser ?  Would you just put the %%~n1 -> a variable like %%t or something ...then just echo %%t later in the script?

Comment: in that case use @aschipfl solution , he is doing basically the same thing but storing all the names in array variables (the ones like ITEM[1] ..ITEM[2] etc.
then in the notifyuser part use the last part of his solution , since the variable is already set, which outputs each ITEM[n] until he reaches the total.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably provided in [@dbenham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36090893). However, I want to give an answer without using a temporary file but (a) variable(s) to store the list of text files.

---

The following script is based on your `for /R` approach and builds up a comma-separated list of found `*.txt` files (each one enclosed in `""`) and stores it in the variable `ITEMS`. A standard `for` loop is used to display the list items in case the amount exceeds the predefined limit. Here it is:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "LOCATION=.."
set "PATTERN=*.txt"
set /A LIMIT=2

set /A COUNT=0
set "ITEMS="
pushd "%LOCATION%" && (
    for /R "." %%F in ("%PATTERN%") do (
        set /A COUNT+=1
        set "ITEM=%%~F"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "delims=" %%S in ("!ITEMS!"!ITEM!",") do (
            endlocal
            set "ITEMS=%%S"
        )
    )
    popd
)
if %COUNT% GTR %LIMIT% (
    echo Cannot continue script, too many "%PATTERN%" files ^(%COUNT%^) encountered:
    for %%F in (%ITEMS%) do (
        echo(%%~F
    )
    exit /B
)

rem Continue script here...

endlocal
exit /B
```

Since the size of an environment variable and ther length of a command line are limited (on Windows 7 x64, 8191 bytes both, I think), this method may fail for a huge number of `*.txt` files found.

---

This script is slightly different and uses array-like variables `ITEM[1]`, `ITEM[2]`, `ITEM[3]`, etc. to store the encountered `*.txt` files (one each).

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "LOCATION=.."
set "PATTERN=*.txt"
set /A LIMIT=2

set /A COUNT=0
pushd "%LOCATION%" && (
    for /R "." %%F in ("%PATTERN%") do (
        set /A COUNT+=1
        set "ITEM=%%~F"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%S in ("!COUNT!|!ITEM!") do (
            endlocal
            set "ITEM[%%S]=%%T"
        )
    )
    popd
)
if %COUNT% GTR %LIMIT% (
    echo Cannot continue script, too many "%PATTERN%" files ^(%COUNT%^) encountered:
    for /L %%F in (1,1,%COUNT%) do (
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!ITEM[%%F]!
        endlocal
    )
    exit /B
)

rem Continue script here...

endlocal
exit /B
```

Here the environment size (the space holding all of the environment variables) is the limitation; I do not know the limit, but it should be rather high.